# Custom size low profile heating elements

Tags: induction-heating

I want to take a 6000 watt 240 volt power controller and a stainless steel 15.5 gallon beer keg and run three separate 2000 watt heating elements at the same time for distilling. I want to use 3 elements so I will get a larger boil area and more  evaporation compared to using a single 6000 or 5500 watt element. My beer keg has a 8 inch ferrule fitting on the top to use as a filling port and I have a 8 inch ferrule cap with a 3 inch ferrule on the top of that to attach a 3 inch x 8 foot rectifier column so I have plenty of room to access inside the keg.

Where can I get 3 low plug side profile heating elements, so that I could use the center element for the power connection and then run a 10 gauge wire conduit to the right an left hand elements, so all 3 can be energized at the same time, and put some kind of low profile plug connector on the center element, so I can unplug the power supply and not have to drag around a 10 gauge power cord that's permanently attached to the keg?

The elements have to be 2000 watts a-piece 3 x 2000 = 6000 watts and be the right size so they could be mounted in the keg at 2, 6 and 10 O'clock positions and be the right size so the elements meet in the center of the keg.

Comment: Is this heater for distilling or for boiling wort?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing with multiple elements in one of my 100 litre (26 USgal) kettles with 2*3KW elements, but rather than go for short elements all arranged on the same plane I have two of them mounted at 4 and 8 O'clock, I went for long low heat density elements and offset the planes of their insertion by 1.5in/4 cm, so they cross in the middle, but do not touch.

I get an amazing boil and very little scorching of the wort; which is great when trying to do a very pale, IPA or pale ale.

Comment: Mr road-  I found the almost perfect heating element assembly @ Brewha equipment. I just have to weld three 2 inch ferrules to the bottom of the keg. The only problem is getting the elements to set in such a way as to be very close to the very bottom of the keg so the elements don't run dry. The bottom of the keg is a concave shape so that if the elements are mounted straight and level, that leaves 3 inches space in the center of the keg that the elements won't reach. If the mash level goes below the heating element it could cause a problem.

Comment: @Thomasedwin: Could you accept or reject this answer?